# Flot: Displaying specific tick labels

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I have a flot graph with y-axis co-ordinates to be 55, 110, 220, 440, 880, 1760.

I want all the six ticks to be displayed but I donot want the tick label 55 and 1760 to be displayed.

Is it possible through Flot Charts?

Thanx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your options pass a ticks array with an empty label at those positions:

```
yaxis: {
  ticks: [[55, ""], [110, "label"], [220, "label"], [440, "label"], [880, "label"], [1760, ""]]
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9x7aJ/1670/).