# jQuery Flot skipping x-axis values

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, flot

I read through most of the documentation of Flot, but didn't really find anything relevant.

Currently my flot graph looks as following:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IRAIrjQ.png]

and since there is no data in the middle row, I would love to be able to hide it, but still show the data from the first and last 2 x-axis columns.

The way I define the x-axis values is as following:

```
var options = [{[1, '1-1-2013'], [2, '1-4-2013'], [3, '1-7-2013'], 
[4, '1-10-2013'], [5, '1-1-2014']}];
```

and that works fine, since I plot on the data values according to the first number of each element, which is a date Id of some sort.

To explain it better, I would like my graph to look rougly like this instead:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/4W3plD4.png]

Comment: So you dont want to plot ticks if corresponding data is zero?

Comment: Exactly. On my x-axis' 3rd tick, there is no data. I would like to hide that tick then.

Answer (score 2):

You could manually change your data series to omit all empty values, but then you have to also specify your ticks (and labels) manually.

For example if you data is something like

```
data = [
    ['1-1-2013', 2.5],
    ['1-2-2013', 2.0],
    ['1-3-2013', 0.0],
    ['1-4-2013', 2.2]
];
```

your data would then change to

```
data = [
    [0, 2.5],
    [1, 2.0],
    [2, 2.2]
];
```

and your x-axis ticks would be

```
ticks = [
    [0, '1-1-2013'],
    [1, '1-2-2013'],
    [2, '1-4-2013']
];
```

The possibly code for this:

```
var newdata = [];
var newticks = [];

function changeData(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, element) {
        if (element[1] != 0.0) {
            newdata.push([ newdata.length, element[1] ]);
            newticks.push([ newticks.length, element[0] ]);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, but my issue with this is that I am using (as you might see in the jsfiddle) datasets with more than 1 value per x-axis tick, and all of it is added programmatically, which makes it a lot more complex to change afterwards.

Comment: More complex but not impossible. If your data is complex there is no easy solution. Maybe do the calculations on the server side before sending the data to the client?

Answer (score 1):

You either can use tick for-matter function to return null if value is zero else while specifying tick array, pass empty string for corresponding value.

```
var ticks = [
          [1, '1-1-2013'], 
          [2, '1-4-2013'],
          [3, ''], 
          [4, '1-10-2013'], 
          [5, '1-1-2014']
];
```

Or

```
xaxis: {
     tickFormatter: function(v, axis) {
        if(v != 0) {
            return "<span class='axisLabel'>" + v + "%</span>";
        } else {
            return "";
        }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that still keep the tick, but just not have a description on the tick? Also, when I try to use your code in my example, it changes nothing at all, for some reason.

Comment: @LarsJensen Fiddle plz? Refer [Flot: Displaying specific tick labels](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335856/flot-displaying-specific-tick-labels).It should work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Fc3J/ - I have no idea how to add the external flot library to the JSFiddle, but this is generally the code I'm using at the moment.

Comment: I changed the question to have a graphical representation of what I want the graph to look like, it might give you a clearer idea of what I want.

Comment: I understood your question now.Actually this is not possible with flot.You cannot skip tick and print next in place. There is already a open question for it.[Flot:Hide specific tick labels and print next label in place](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17484066/flothide-specific-tick-labels-and-print-next-label-in-place).All you can do is print an empty label in place.